# How to make a scooped corner in react native

Tags: css, react-native, styles

I am working on react native chat feature and I need help in making scooped corner for the message box.
like the below images

[image]

[image]

Comment: If have any idea than I will never post my question here. Btw I search for it and found HTML css example but react native styling is different and I cannot convert that to react native css

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of creating the CSS for a speech bubble. Many seem to use CSS border to draw the triangle. And the older examples at least tend to use fixed units.

Here is CSS for a speech bubble which attempts to be responsive, but without allowing the font size to get too small.

CSS variables for radius, padding etc can be set independently. What the code does is to set up the rectangle with the quote in it in a standard way, then adds an after pseudo element to draw the triangle using a linear-gradient as the background image. The dimensions of this 'pointy bit' can also be altered if required, for example to make it longer.

[image]

```css
.speech-bubble {
    --background: navy;
    --paddingsides: max(1.5vw, 20px);
    --paddingtopbottom: max(1vw, 10px);
    --radius: max(0.5vw, 5px);
    color: lightBlue;
    background-color: var(--background);
    border-radius: var(--radius);
    font-size: max(1.5vw, 20px);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: var(--paddingtopbottom) var(--paddingsides) var(--paddingtopbottom) var(--paddingsides);
    position: absolute;
}

.speech-bubble::after {
    --h: max(0.75vw, 10px);
    height: var(--h);
    width: var(--h);
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, var(--background) 50%, var(--background) 100%);
    top: 100%;
    right: max(var(--paddingsides), var(--radius));
    position: absolute;
    content: "";    
}
```

```html
    <div class="speech-bubble">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you but my question is how to convert that to react native css because react native styling is different react native does not support :after and many other css properties

Comment: Whoops, sorry I didn't read the question carefully enough.

Comment: it's ok at least you give the answer, not  like the other who criticise. Thank you

Comment: I don’t know enough about React native limitations. I guess we’d have to use two divs instead of one? That wouldn’t be so nice of course. Is there a definitive description of what is and isn’t supported, I can’t find anything totally official.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021886/where-can-i-find-all-list-of-style-properties-supported-by-react-native
https://github.com/vhpoet/react-native-styling-cheat-sheet

Comment: Thanks I’ll follow it up. Is this of any use as a pointer to making a speech bubble? It’s a start but not so good on Android perhaps [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465450/chat-bubble-in-react-native